# NiFi Controller Service Reuse and Schema Registry Architecture

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, confluent-platform

When creating Apache NiFi controller services, I'm interested in hearing about when it makes sense to create new ones and when to re-share existing ones.

Currently I have a `CsvReader` and `CSVRecordSetWriter` at the root process group and they are reused heavily in child process groups. I have tried to set them up to be as dynamic and flexible as possible to cover the widest number of use cases possible. I am setting the Schema Text property in each currently like this:

```
Reader Schema Text: ${avro.schema:notNull():ifElse(${avro.schema}, ${avro.schema.reader})}
Writer Schema Text: ${avro.schema:notNull():ifElse(${avro.schema}, ${avro.schema.writer})}
```

A very common pattern I have is to map files with different fields from different sources into a common format (common schema). So one thought is to use the `ConvertRecord` or `UpdateRecord` processors with `avro.schema.reader` and `avro.schema.writer`attributes set to the input and output schemas. Then I would have the writer always set the `avro.schema` attribute so any time I read records again further along in a flow it would default to using `avro.schema`. This feels dirty to leave the reader and writer schema attributes hanging around. Is there a better way from an architecture standpoint? Why have tons of controller services hanging around at different levels? Aside from some settings that may need to be different for some use cases, am I missing anything?

Also curious in hearing about how others organize their schemas? I don't have a need to reuse them at disparate locations across different processor blocks or reference different versions so it seems like a waste to centralize them or maintain a schema registry server that will also require upgrades and maintenance when I can just use `AvroSchemaRegistry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided it made more sense to split the controller into two controllers. One for conversions from **Schema A** to **Schema B** and another for using the same `avro.schema` property as normal/default readers and writers do when adding new ones. This allows for explicitly choosing the right pattern at processor block configuration time rather than relying on the implicit configuration of a single processor. Plus you get the added benefit of not stopping all flows (just a subset) when you only need to tweak settings on one of those two patterns.